# Use of テロ in 飯テロ

Tags: etymology, slang

Why is テロ, which is presumably derived from "terrorism", used in 飯{めし}テロ, which I assume is the Japanese for "food porn"?

I checked jisho.org and couldn't find any slang meanings of テロ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [NicoNicoPedia](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E9%A3%AF%E3%83%86%E3%83%AD) explains:

> 飯テロとは、善良な市民に対し無差別に食欲を沸き立たせる、残忍で卑劣極まりない行為である。
>   これらの行為を絶対に許してはならない。これらの行為に決して屈してはならない。
>   Meshi-tero is a most brutal and cowardly act which indiscriminately makes virtuous citizens feel hunger. We must absolutely not allow or give in to these acts.

Or as [Hatena Keyword](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/keyword/%C8%D3%A5%C6%A5%ED) says:

> 食欲をそそる料理や食べ物の画像（唐揚げ、ラーメンなど）をweb上にアップし、見る者を空腹感で悶えさせるテロ行為のこと。
>   Meshi-tero is an act of terrorism where one uploads pictures of appetizing food (karaage, ramen, etc.) to the web which makes those who see the pictures writhe with hunger.

So the 'terrorism' here refers to how it makes people feel hungry. But obviously it's just funny; nobody considers it terrorism. And you're right, it's the equivalent of 'food porn' in English.

Comment: My immediate thought was (in addition to making people hungry) was that they would get hungry for unhealthy stuff, and slowly destroy themselves by eating.